# Function field of real elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $B$ be a smooth elliptic curve over $\mathbb{R}$. Then, what is its function field $\mathbb{R}(B)$? More precisely, I need to understand if the quadratic form $x^2+y^2+z^2$ represents zero over $\mathbb{R}(B)$.

Comment: What is the relation of $(x,y,z)$ and the curve $B$? How is $B$ given? If with an affine equation (such as Weierstrass), then I don't understand what $z$ is. If it is given as a projective curve with a cubic homogeneous equation, then how could that quadratic vanish on all of $B$? The (projective) circle you get as zero locus of the quadratic only intersects a cubic at finitely many points.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is no direct relation. My initial goal was to understand what are (finite) subgroups of $PGL(2,\mathbb{R}(B))$ which (after some work) reduces to my question (as $PGL(2,K)\cong SO(K,x^2+yz)$)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: the question makes perfect sense, and is not about intersecting a cubic and a conic. It is simply asking whether there are rational functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ on $B$, not all zero, such that $f^2+g^2+h^2=0$ identically on $B$.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @Nefertiti. I completely missed the boat on this one :-/

Comment: If $f_i$ are *any* finite collection of *any* real valued rational functions on *any* set $X$, then $\sum f^2_i = 0$ trivially implies that all the $f_i$ are zero. An element in $\mathbf{R}(B)$ certainly restricts to give a real valued rational function on $B(\mathbf{R})$, so any $x,y,z \in \mathbf{R}(B)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ will have to vanish on $B(\mathbf{R})$. But non-zero rational functions can only have finitely many zeros, and $B(\mathbf{R})$ is infinite, so $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: Closely related: the function field of an integral affine variety over $\mathbf{R}$ with a non-singular $\mathbf{R}$-point is formally real.